# Setting up multiple email configurations in Code Igniter using config/email.php

Tags: email, codeigniter, configuration

I am using Code Igniter 2.0.3.

I am having various roles in my application and I want to set up various email configurations depending upon those roles.

As per [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) we can set up the configurations in config/email.php for one account, but I want to set up multiple accounts, so that depending upon the role I just call the role at run time and my settings are initialized automatically.

Sample code could be

```
$config['first_setting']['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['first_setting']['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['first_setting']['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['first_setting']['smtp_user'] = 'j@j.j';
$config['first_setting']['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config['first_seeting']);
```

Gracias.

Comment: Which email configs do you want to be different for each user?

Comment: does this not work? that looks correct to me. The `initialize` method takes an array of config items -- that's what you're passing to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the config file to set the email class up.

When you "call the role" depending on the role it can set those settings at runtime with its own settings based on role data.

for example you'll have something like this:

```
function login(){
  //do login stuff

  //email settings for this user / role
  $this->load->library('email'); //ensure its loaded
  $conf['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
  $conf['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
  $conf['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
  $conf['smtp_user'] = $this->session->userdata('email'); //user/role specific settings
  $conf['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

  $this->email->initialize($conf);
}
```

From there on out when you use the email class it will be sent using these settings. (provided you don't overwrite them latter)